# Reading content of a cell

Tags: vba, excel, cell, libreoffice

I would like to read content of cell in libreoffice. It seems very easy, but some cells of the sheet contains such values:

```
=@p1or &quot
```

They are actually no formula. The are only some text. In my sheet I am seeing `Err:508` in Cells instead of the text (but at the top of the sheet, or if I double-click on the cell, I can see the content).

The problem is, If I want to read the content of the cells:

```
Sheet.getCellByPosition(J, I).String
  Sheet.getCellByPosition(J, I).Value
  Sheet.getCellByPosition(J, I).getValue()
```

all of them return me  `Err:508` instead of the content.

How can I read the content of the cell correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have libreoffice so can't test, but maybe try .text or .formula ?